# Prepared Statement with Select? Possible?

Tags: c++, sqlite, prepared-statement

is it possible to use prepared statements with the SELECT command?

I wrote in C++ following code:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(this->ppGetStmt, 1, id);

int rc = sqlite3_step(this->ppGetStmt);
//sqlite3_result_int(this->ppGetStmt, &value);

sqlite3_reset(this->ppGetStmt);
```

The SQL statement looks like following `SELECT value FROM test WHERE id=?;`.
But how can I get the **value** out of the statement?

I consult sqlite.org, but can't find any helpful informations.

**EDIT:**
Solution can found here: http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html chapter 1.1.

Comment: Are you saying you answered your own question?

Comment: Yeah, but thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each call to [sqlite3_step()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) for which you receive a SQLITE_ROW return value, you use the [column access functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) to get your values out.